# Pass Python object as argument to function in "parfeval"

Tags: python, matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

I am trying to pass one Python object as an argument to a function that I am evaluating in the background with parfeval. The Python object is an instance of a Python class, and I detail it below. However, to reproduce the error, I will exemplify with a Python dictionary... However, simply using struct(pydict) would not work because I would lose all the attributes and methods in the Python class.

Assume the Python dictionary is

```matlab
o = py.dict(pyargs('soup',3.57,'bread',2.29,'bacon',3.91,'salad',5.00));
```

and the function is

```matlab
function t = testFunc(x)
t = x{'soup'};
end
```

If I evaluate the function, I get the correct answer:

```matlab
>> testFunc(o)
ans =
3.5700
```

However, if I use `parfeval`, I get the following error:

```matlab
>> f = parfeval(@testFunc,1,o);
>> fetchOutputs(f)
Error using parallel.Future/fetchOutputs
One or more futures resulted in an error.
Caused by:
Error using testFunc (line 2)
Invalid or deleted object.
```

Is there a workaround to this error that doesn't mean I have to recode my whole Python class?
Here is the preview of the object I want to pass as a function to `parfeval`:

```matlab
clt = 
    Python Client with properties:
    enforce_enums: 1
    api_key: [1×45 py.str]
    request_number: [1×1 py.int]
    logger: [1×1 py.logging.Logger]
    session: [1×1 py.authlib.integrations.httpx_client.oauth2_client.OAuth2Client]
    token_metadata: [1×1 py.tda.auth.TokenMetadata]
    <tda.client.synchronous.Client object at 0x000001ECA08EAE50>
```

I didn't find any restrictions in the documentation that says that `parfeval` function inputs cannot be anything...
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/parfeval.html

> "X1,...,Xm — Input arguments
> comma-separated list of variables or expressions... Input arguments, specified as a comma-separated list of variables or expressions"

Comment: `return x{'soup'}`? - Am I missing something?

Comment: In matlab you declare the return variable when you declare the function (here it is t). You can use return too, but do not have to.

Comment: Are you using a parallel pool in the threaded model or in the process model? I presume in the latter you would need to instantiate a Python interpreter in each process, and somehow copy over the python variable.

Comment: @CrisLuengo could you tell me a bit more about how to instantiate a python interpreter in each process and copy the python variable? are there any examples in the matlab documentation?

Comment: I have no idea how to do this. I just imagine this would be necessary because each instance of MATLAB, being a separate process, would not have access to the other’s Python interpreter. The MATLAB object is copied, but not the stuff inside the Python interpreter that is referenced by that MATLAB object. This is either difficult to do right, or simply impossible.

Comment: In the case of the threaded parallel pool, all threads would share the Python interpreter, but I don’t know if it is possible to call Python functions from multiple threads without breaking things. I hope someone with experience in this area sees your question!

Comment: @CrisLuengo thanks for your comment Cris.. this is what I got when creating a threaded pool and executing the same function above with the python dict.. "Use of class or function dict is not supported on a thread-based worker. Use a process-based parallel pool instead."  I guess I would not be able to use threading?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the [limitations of the MATLAB->Python support](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/limitations-to-python-support.html) is that Python objects cannot be serialized. `parfeval` (and other parallel constructs) require serialization to transfer data from one MATLAB process to another.

You might be able to work around this by having each worker build the data structure directly and storing it / accessing it via [`parallel.pool.Constant`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/parallel.pool.constant.html), like this:

```
oC = parallel.pool.Constant(@() py.dict(pyargs('soup',3.57,'bread',2.29,'bacon',3.91,'salad',5.00)));
fetchOutputs(parfeval(@(c) c.Value{'salad'}, 1, oC))
```